# Git list : viewing git repositories in home folder

Tags: git

I have installed GitList for repository view of my git repositories.  However, GitList lists only the repositories created inside the directory "/var/www/html".  I have other git repositories in my home folder e.g., /home/myhome/public, but unable to view them with GitList even after changing gitlist/config.ini.  Have I missed out anything for not getting /home folders in gitlist? Any help??